# Como fazer um formulário com 2 páginas ou mais no Ireport

Tags: ireport

Preciso fazer um formulário para ser preenchido com dados do sistema no `Ireport`. Até ai tudo bem, com uma página eu consigo, mas e com 2 páginas? Ou seja, um formulário que são 2 folhas.

Eu vi algumas pessoas sugerindo se fazer 2 `details` e colocar quebra de página, ou fazer um `group report` mas ambas soluções me parecem estranhas. Pois eu queria usar o recurso de usar o title para aparecer na primeira página do titulo do meu formulário e em cada página, ou seja, na primeira e segunda páginas, no final, aparecer um rodapé contendo um contador de páginas. No que faço com uma página, uso o `Title` para colocar o titulo que aparece somente uma vez e o `summary` para aparecer o rodapé contador de páginas.

Quando utilizei as 2 soluções acima citadas não ficou bom, alguém com maior experiência poderia me explicar como fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Por fim, resolvi meu problema colocando uma página inteira, ocupada totalmente pela banda `detail` e inseri os elementos nela, o lado ruim foi ter que mover o componentes novamente. Mas deu para aprender um pouco mais. O contador de páginas foi no braço.